# Python searching items in sulbist for a listA of items and returning index of not found items in listA

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sublist

```
listA = ['HM', 'GL', 'WD', 'HM', 'WD', 'HM', 'WD']

sublist = [['HM','GL'], ['GL'], ['WD','HM'], ['WD','GL'], ['WD'], ['HM','WD'], ['HM']]
```

Both `list` and `sublist` are of equal lengths, the output should be mismatching index, i.e. `[3,5]` index number of `list` are not found in corresponding `sublist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think correct answer should be `[3, 6]`:

```
listA = ['HM', 'GL', 'WD', 'HM', 'WD', 'HM', 'WD']
sublist = [['HM','GL'], ['GL'], ['WD','HM'], ['WD','GL'], ['WD'], ['HM','WD'], ['HM']]

print([i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(listA, sublist)) if not a in b])
```

Prints:

```
[3, 6]
```